# Fire javascript function when app goes into background

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode4.5

My app has a timer that is supposed to fire when the app is in the background, however, due to ios quirks, my onPause function isn't fired until it the app is resumed. I have been researching ways to fire a javascript funciton from obj-C, but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have the following code

```
// CUSTOM CODE TO DETECT APP STATE
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"onPause;"];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

NSLog(@"OBJ-C paused");
```

}

My js code looks like so;

```
function onPause() {
            console.log("JS paused");
        }
```

When the app goes into the background, I can seem my OBJ-C log, but cannot get the js log and when i start the app back up, the timer has not paused.

Can anyone with help or advise me as to what I am doing wrong, I have no experience with OBJ-C and am using Phonegap 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
In the following link [here](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/). There are 2 undocumented events; resign and active which made it work as should for my purposes.

```
document.addEventListener("resign", resign, false);
document.addEventListener("active", active, false);

        function resign() {
            // pause code fired
        }

        function active() {
            //resume code fired
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `applicationWillResignActive:`.

The app probably doesn't react anymore if the app was already sent to background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this didn't work, there is no console.log for the js function and the timer still continues to run